# How to list products in 2 sets of ordered <ol> list in list mode?

Tags: category, product-list

I have set the Category products to List mode which shows products inside ordered list  which shows one set of ordered list. I would like to make the 2 ordered list. How do I accomplish it?

### Update:

Below is the screenshot of the products how I wanted to list them and a link to JSFIDDLE
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=AgdLgQLA7o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme's CSS file find the class

```
.products-list
```

and add this:

```
width: 100%;
```

Then find the class:

```
.products-list li.item
```

And add this:

```
width: 50%;
float: left;
```

This then will display your list in 2 columns. It may need a bit more tweaking for your theme to get it to look good.

Comment: it works but the products `li` are listed from left to right and again left but I want to display one set of `<ol>` in left and another `<ol>` set to right.

Comment: That methodology would take a fair amount of development as it would require creating 2 <ol> objects, with the 2nd <ol> column starting at the product following the last in <ol> number 1's list.

Comment: looks like. For now I have to use the css method you have described.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are trying to get your List View to be in 2 columns.
You can do this using the following steps:

1. In Magento backend go to Catalog->Manage Categories
2. Select the category you want to have 2 columns
3. Click the 'Custom Design' tab
4. Select a 2 column page layout from the drop down.
5. Add this to the Custom Layout Update text box:

```
 <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>2</columns></action>
     </reference>
```

You will need to repeat this for any categories you want 2 columns of products on.

Comment: the solution you have given only works when the List Mode is set to Grid not List mode..

Comment: Hey kevin, have posted another answer too but this also only appears to alter Grid mode. Let me have another look at this one.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Please check the newest answer, the simple changes to the CSS will set you on the right track hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template in `app/design/[your template]/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Default would be `app/design/base/default/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of columns in your themes list.phtml file.

If using the default theme that would be here:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Then find this line:

```
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
```

Change it to this:

```
    <?php $_columnCount = 2 ?>
```

Comment: This also only works correctly for Grid View.